# Laravel Jetstream Vue mixin route

Tags: laravel, vue.js, webpack, laravel-jetstream

In a new Laravel project created by the installer with the Jetstream option `resources/js/app.js` has a line that reads:
`Vue.mixin({ methods: { route } });`

PHPStorm reports that `route` is an unresolved variable or type. This happens, PHPStorm can be wrong. In a newly created application this does not cause an error.

However, when I upgraded an existing project to Laravel 8.10.0 and installed Jetstream via composer this **does** cause and issue. When running this `npm run dev` does not error, but the browser will report `app.js:44258 Uncaught ReferenceError: route is not defined`.

I can find no difference in `app.js` or `bootstrap.js` that would cause this. Where does this get imported or included so that I can check if it was done correctly in my upgrade?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The newly created app and the update both create a Blade template that includes the `@routes` directive. As I was comparing existing files I did not notice this difference.

This can be corrected by including the `@routes` directive in your blade template prior to the main scripts being loaded, as documented in the [installation guide for ziggy](https://github.com/tighten/ziggy#installation).

Answer (score 0):

With the suggestion of ToothlessRebel, this is how I solved my error :

Step 1 command line :

```
composer require tightenco/ziggy
npm install ziggy-js
php artisan ziggy:generate "resources/js/ziggy.js"
```

step 2 : modify webpack.mix.js :

```
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    ...
    .webpackConfig(require('./webpack.config'));
```

And in ./webpack.config :

```
const path = require('path');
module.exports = {
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            '@': path.resolve('resources/js'),
            ziggy: path.resolve('vendor/tightenco/ziggy/src/js/route.js'),
        },
    },
};
```

Step 3 : app.js :

```
import route from 'ziggy';
import {
    Ziggy
} from './ziggy';
...
Vue.mixin({
    methods: {
        route: (name, params, absolute) => route(name, params, absolute, Ziggy),
    },
});
...
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    render: (h) =>
        h(InertiaApp, {
            props: {
                initialPage: JSON.parse(app.dataset.page),
                resolveComponent: (name) => require(`./Pages/${name}`).default,
            },
        }),

});
```

and finally a command : `npm run dev`

So, my dashboard and all mixin/ziggy routes are working...
Not anymore my vue-router routes ... I guess I have a conflit I have to resolve, but it's an other problem